# Serial com register formula

Tags: c

i am working on a atmega328p, learning to uses its registers instead a coding with common arduino code.

i've found this formula to get the baud rate on the Serial port (using USART protocol) :

[image]

how could i type this in C language ? or specifically in the arduino IDE ?

--

i made some researches and discovered that it could write it that way :

```
float _baudrate = (16000000/(16*9600));
```

then i convert the value to int (because i need an integer value)

```
int _baudrate_int = (int)_baudrate;enter code here
```

all this for a 9600 baudrate of course.

But when i do this, i don't understand why, the code does not calculate it right. i'm supposed to have 103-104 and i get 710.

it will work if i type (16*9600) product manually. Which is 153600

```
float _baudrate = (16000000/153600);
```

then i get the right baudrate result. but what if i want the code to calculate everything ? how can i do ?

where's my mistake with this line of code ?

```
float _baudrate = (16000000/(16*9600));
```

Comment: how would you do it on paper?

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to provide the source you have so far. Please add where specifically you are stumbling. BTW, general C questions are better asked on [so], especially if they don't have a relation to Arduino. But it is fine here, since you are asking about the Arduino IDE. Are you aware that you are programming C++ if you use the Arduino IDE? C++ and C are different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

> ```cpp
> float _baudrate = (16000000/(16*9600)
> ```

other than the missing parenthesis and semicolon, you have an integer
overflow. The issue is that, on AVR-based Arduinos, an `int` is only
16-bits long. The constants `16` and `9600` being small enough to fit in
an `int`, they are implicitly given the `int` type. Then, their
multiplication is also done with the `int` type, and the product
overflows and wraps modulo 2<sup>16</sup> to 22528.

You can fix this by giving either or both of these numbers the `L`
suffix, which will make them use the `long` data type. Alternatively, if
you want a floating point calculation, you can use `.0` as a suffix.

Not that the avr-libc provides a header file with some macros for this
calculation, which is then done by the preprocessor:
[<util/setbaud.h>: Helper macros for baud rate
calculations](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__setbaud.html). You can use them as follows:

```cpp
#define BAUD 9600
#include <util/setbaud.h>

void set_baud_rate() {
    UBRR0 = UBRR_VALUE;
#if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= _BV(U2X0);
#else
    UCSR0A &= ~_BV(U2X0);
#endif
}
```

**Edit:**

To answer the question in a comment: yes, the `L` suffix creates a
`long` constant, and is thus similar to creating a `long` variable
(except it is a constant instead of a variable).

I suggest you take a look at the line below from setbaud.h. In the case
where U2X0 is not needed, the baud rate register value is computed as:

```c
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 8UL * (BAUD)) / (16UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)
```

A few things to note:

- It is all computed with integers, no floating point. Actually, the
  computation is performed by the compiler, at build time, not by the
  Arduino.
- The suffix `UL` is for `unsigned long`
- Adding 8 before dividing by 16 is a way to round the result to the
  nearest integer, instead of rounding to zero. Ties are rounded up.
- There is `-1UL` at the end, as this is required by the UART hardware
  (it is in the formula from the datasheet).

Comment: yeah i know for the missing parenthesis and semicolon. just made a wrong ctrl+c ctrl+v.

Comment: I added the L suffix and it worked. impressive, it works ! and i understand what you explained and the fact it will make them use long data type. i have an other little question : is putting the L suffix the same that doing an other variable and make it = (long)variable ? if you see what i mean

Comment: yes i understand. the same formula with a 8-addition and giving it long type before rounding it and converting to integer.